# Dividing 3D array by 2D row sums?

Tags: python, numpy, 3d, division

I have a 3D numpy array ary[tbl_idx, rows, cols], which represent multiple 2D tables.
I want to sum every row in every table and then divide every element of every table by the corresponding row-sum.

I.e. every table is row-probability based..

I can do the row-sums in the following way :

```
ary.sum(axis=2).astype(np.float)
```

but can't figure out how to do the correct division 3D-ary/2D-row-sums.

Do you know how ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `keepdims=1`to keep the number of dimensions while summing and then simply perform the division, like so -

```
ary/ary.sum(axis=2, keepdims=1).astype(np.float)
```

Alternatively, if you already have the summation saved, we could extend it to `3D` by introducing a new axis with `None/np.newaxis` and then perform the division, like so -

```
ary/ary.sum(axis=2).astype(np.float)[...,None]
```

---

For the summations that are `zeros`, you would get `NaNs` and `Infs` in the correspoding positions in the output. To set those as `zeros` in the output, one way is to use `np.where` -

```
sums = ary.sum(axis=1,keepdims=1)
out = np.where(sums!=0, ary/sums.astype(np.float),0)
```

Alternatively, use the earlier code to get the division output and finally look for finite ones and set rest as `zeros` -

```
np.where(np.isfinite(out1), out1,0) # out1 is o/p from earlier section
```

Comment: super cool ;), is there some way to set to ZERO all nan's and inf. I can add 1 before the operation but was wondering if there is a shortcut.

Comment: I did this : ary[np.isnan(ary)] = 0. Will close the question , because you answered my primary question, thanks.